# Angular2 radio button selected value getting changed

Tags: angular, radio-button

I have written a a radio button html code like this

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of options.data;" class="input-lists">
        <input type="radio" name="{{item.fieldName}}" [value]="item.value"
        [checked]="item.checked" (change)="handleRadioClick(data, item.value)"
        [name] ="data.id" [id]="data.id"> 
    </div>
```

and the typescript function like this

```
handleRadioClick(options, val) {
    options.value = val;
    this.form[options.id] = val;
  }
```

Here let's say i have radio options like 'yes' and 'No' when i select the 'No' value it's getting saved to the `this.form` variable but when i try to save the form the value is getting changed to `yes` again.

data variable has

```
{
  fieldName: 'decision',
  id: '4556888ee',
  options:[{
       value: 'yes',
       checked: true
       },
      {
        value: 'No',
        checked: false
      }]
}
```

Comment: The code you provided is not complete.

Comment: Maybe you can provide us a plunker? Here is a good template to get started: https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=catalogue

Comment: @Kinduser what more information do you need??

Comment: For example - `options` variable, the whole form etc.

Comment: @Kinduser done added the options

Comment: @kohli It's still not complete. Please post your whole code inside plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/lL307M6VjxtqvoNEiD9Q - then save it and give me the link.